# How to change color palette of my highcharter bar plot

Tags: r, highcharts, colors, r-highcharter

I'm trying to create an highcharter bar chart with a shiny input selector in an r markdown document.
My problem is that i can't change colors of the bar to make them match the colors i have chosen for my report. It is the first time i use highcharter and probably i'm missing something about the philosophy of highcharter aesthetic

```
library(tidyverse)
library(highcharter)
        
df <- tibble(category = c('A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4','A5'),
                         n = c(3415,3701,2898,2409,1886))
mypal <- c("#BC3C29FF", "#0072B5FF", "#E18727FF", 
           "#20854EFF", "#7876B1FF", "#6F99ADFF","#FFDC91FF","#EE4C97FF")
            
df %>% 
arrange(desc(n)) %>%
hchart( type = 'bar', hcaes(x = category, y = n, color = category))%>%
hc_title(text = 'Most Reported Categories') %>% 
hc_xAxis(title = '') %>%
hc_add_theme(hc_theme_elementary()) %>% 
hc_colors(mypal)
```

The code does not seem to care about the last line hc_colors and the following is my output

[image: my first output]

My goal is to have different colors for every bar (something similar to ggplot2::scale_fill), but i want the colors to be chosen from `mypal`

I have tried

```
df %>% 
arrange(desc(n)) %>%
hchart( type = 'bar', hcaes(x = category, y = n), color = category)%>%
hc_title(text = 'Most Reported Categories') %>% 
hc_xAxis(title = '') %>%
hc_add_theme(hc_theme_elementary()) %>% 
hc_colors(mypal)
```

And

```
df %>% 
arrange(desc(n)) %>%
hchart( type = 'bar', hcaes(x = category, y = n), color = mypal)%>%
hc_title(text = 'Most Reported Categories') %>% 
hc_xAxis(title = '') %>%
hc_add_theme(hc_theme_elementary()) %>% 
hc_colors(mypal)
```

Especially the latter gives me this bizarre output.

[image: My second output (actually funny but not what i want)]

I have been working on this for hours not reaching any satisfactory result. As I said before the solution is probably obvious and I'm missing something about how `highcharter` works.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a column with the colors you want to give each bar. Here is an example using `mutate` by calling the column "mypal" with the first five colors of your vector:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(highcharter)
#> Registered S3 method overwritten by 'quantmod':
#>   method            from
#>   as.zoo.data.frame zoo

df <- tibble(category = c('A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4','A5'),
             n = c(3415,3701,2898,2409,1886))
mypal <- c("#BC3C29FF", "#0072B5FF", "#E18727FF", 
           "#20854EFF", "#7876B1FF", "#6F99ADFF","#FFDC91FF","#EE4C97FF")

df %>% 
  mutate(mypal = mypal[1:5]) %>%
  arrange(desc(n)) %>%
  hchart( type = 'bar', hcaes(x = category, y = n, color = mypal))%>%
  hc_title(text = 'Most Reported Categories') %>% 
  hc_xAxis(title = '') %>%
  hc_add_theme(hc_theme_elementary())
```

[image]
<sup>Created on 2022-09-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>